# how to pass jquery variable to django view

Tags: jquery, python, django, django-views

Summary: I am creating a web page which shows the results of user selections. I have two files. html and jquery. I have created a variable reports_array = [ ] which collects all the selections of user when "Done" button is clicked.

Issue: I have to pass reports_array[ ] values to the django view.

Here is the code for jquery

```
.on('click','.done', function(){

    var report_array = [];
    report_array.push(
        {
            Layer_Table: layer_array,
            Benefits_Table: benefits_array,
            Map_Layer_selection: save_selection_layer,
            Map_Benefits_selection: save_selection_benefits,
        });
    console.log(report_array);
```

Here is the code for view.py

```
def done(request):
template = loader.get_template('maps/done.html')
context = RequestContext(request, { 
    'reports_link': report_array,  //I believe this is not correct.
    })    

return HttpResponse(template.render(context))
```

how to pass report_array from jquery to this "context"...????
assume done.html contains following code

```
<head>  
    <title>Reports</title>  
</head>  
<body>  
    <p>{{ reports_link }}</p>
</body>
```

I am new to django interface. Assume url.py is correct. I am looking for logic that i am missing here.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure I understood how you want to present the report array. But to pass JQuery array to Django view you can use AJAX call to Django URL

```
var obj = {'report_array': report_array}
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: '/DESTINATION_URL/',
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8', //EDITED
    data: JSON.stringify(obj),
    success: function(data) {
         $('body').html(data); //EDITED
    },
    error: function(rs, e) {     
         alert(rs.responseText);                
    }
});
```

Then in your views.py

```
import json
from django.template.loader import render_to_string

def done(request):
    params = json.loads(request.body)
    report_array = params['report_array']
    html_data = render_to_string('maps/done.html', {'reports_link': report_array})

    return HttpResponse(html_data)
```

Then your done.html can just be this:

```
<body>  
<p>{{ reports_link }}</p>
</body>
```

This way AJAX will render your page to show the report_array on success. So it will change the content of body without reloading the page.

Comment: Kindly look again into the view.py code. I have edited context. I want to pass reports_array from jquery to "context" in views.py.

Comment: I have tried this logic but i am getting further decoding error like. "the JSON object must be str, not 'bytes'". I have tried related answers from stackoverflow but not helpful. i am using python 3.4. Could you help me out with this one.

Comment: @Rahul I have updated the answer one more time. Try adding utf-8 to contentType in jquery. Btw are you using Python3? Because there are different ways to decode json object