# Django - Pass int and None value to chart.js

Tags: javascript, python, django, chart.js

I'm not really good in javascript, a language I always have difficulties to understand and work with. I'm working on a Django project where I need to pass a list to Chart.js to display a graph according to a specific Model.

The problem I have is trying to pass a list to javascript from Django in order to display data if they are available or not.

Let's say I have a python list from a Model attribute :

```py
[10, 20, None, 30, 40, None, 50]
```

I need Chart.js to display data depending if they is a value for each axis point and nothing if they is None. When I try to pass the list with `json.dump()` and then in my template with `{{ my_list|safe }}` it display it like this :

```json
['10', '20', 'None', '30', '40', 'None', '50']
```

Everything is diplayed as str when it should be either int or None/null value. How should I do if I need chart.js to have values as they are in backend ?

Hoping my problem is clear enough, if not let me know and I'll try to better explain !

Thank you in advance for your precious help.

**Chart.js code**

```
        var ctx = document.getElementById('financial-chart');
        var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
            type: 'line',
            data: {
                labels: {{ tab_year|safe }}",
                datasets:
                [{
                    label: 'Sales',
                    data: {{ tab_sales|safe }},
                    backgroundColor: "#4C81B6",
                    borderColor: "#4C81B6",
                    borderWidth: 3,
                    tension: 0.3,
                    fill: false
                },


                {
                    label: 'Profit',
                    data: {{ tab_profit|safe }},
                    backgroundColor: "#DF5558",
                    borderColor: "#DF5558",
                    borderWidth: 3,
                    tension: 0.3,
                    fill: false

                }]
            },
            options: {
                scales: {
                    y: {
                        beginAtZero: true
                    }
                }
            }
        });
```

**SOLVED**

As mentionned by elyas the extra quotation mark was the reason causing the issue. Nones are now interpreted as null as they should be.

Comment: Can you post the Chart.js template code please? Chart.js shouldn't have an issue with the JSON containing strings instead of ints

Comment: Sorry, I just added the Chart.js code part !

Comment: I can't replicate any issues you're having with the data. I managed to generate the same chart with both a list of strings and a list of ints. But I did notice there's a typo on this line `labels: {{ tab_year|safe }}",` - there's an extraneous quotation mark `"` at the end, which invalidated the JSON and prevented the chart from loading.

Comment: You can try var a = JSON.parse('{{ tab_year | safe }}');. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66712840/django-passing-variables-dynamically-from-views-py-to-jquery/

Comment: The quotation mark was finally the problem ! I can't realise I haven't seen it earlier ... Thanks everyone for your precious help !